# how do i make animation for bezier points smoother/slower with processing.js

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, bezier, p5.js

Im try to do wave with interactive animation on canvas and library Processing.js. This wave must move like water. 
When part of wave interact with mouse coords, transformation is too fast. Whose know how to make this transformation smooth and slow with processing.js/p5.j?

There is a link to this example on codepen: 
https://codepen.io/todoryshyna-maryna/pen/wQbdXO?editors=0010

There is example of code:

```js
function program(proc) {

  var yvalues = [];
  theta = 0.0;
  theta01 = 0.0;
  theta02 = 0.0;

  points = [

    [1583.5, 103.8, 1564.9, 157.4, 1476.2, 157.4],
    [1387.5, 157.4, 1321.2, 119.2, 1200.5, 119.3],
    [1079.7, 119.5, 1046.6, 180.0, 960.0, 180.0],
    [865.7, 180.0, 819.4, 129.4, 699.7, 129.3],
    [580.0, 129.2, 548.6, 159.9, 461.3, 159.9],
    [374.0, 159.9, 361.2, 102.8, 0.0, 90.0],
    [361.2, 75.2, 374.7, 23.9, 461.3, 23.7],
    [547.9, 23.4, 586.3, 59.1, 699.8, 59.1],
    [813.3, 59.1, 865.8, 0.0, 960.0, 0.0],
    [1046.2, 0.0, 1089.3, 67.5, 1199.6, 67.5],
    [1309.9, 67.5, 1387.4, 22.5, 1475.9, 23.3],
    [1564.3, 24.0, 1583.1, 75.2, 1920.0, 90.0],
  ];

  proc.setup = function() {
    width = window.outerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;

    proc.size(width, 450);
    proc.smooth(8);
    proc.frameRate(30);
    proc.strokeWeight(1);
    amplitude = proc.height / 8;
    w = proc.width + 16;

  };


  proc.draw = function() {
    proc.background(255, 255, 255, 0);
    let color = proc.color(0, 255, 199, 100);

    let set = {
      points: points,
      vertex: '',
      color: color,
      animateWave: animateWave1,
    }

    createWave(proc, set, [1920.0, 90.0]);

    proc.noStroke();

  };
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var instance = new Processing(canvas, program);
instance.translate(0, 450 / 4);
instance.scale(0.8, 0.8);


function createWave(proc, props, points) {
  proc.beginShape();
  proc.lineJoin = 'round';
  proc.vertex(points[0], points[1]);
  var pointsLength = props.points.length;

  props.points.forEach((point, index) => {
    props.animateWave(proc, point, index, pointsLength, props.random);
  })
  proc.fill(props.color);
  proc.endShape();
}

function animateWave1(proc, point, index, pointsLength, random) {
  var sin2 = 2;
  var sinHalf = 1.5;
  var ty = proc.bezierTangent(20, 10, 90, 80, 0.5);
  var tx = proc.bezierTangent(85, 10, 90, 15, 0.5);
  var a = proc.atan2(ty, tx);
  a += proc.PI;

  var cy1 = (proc.sin(theta) * amplitude / 3) + (point[1] * proc.sin(sin2));
  var cy2 = (proc.sin(theta) * amplitude / 3) + (point[3] * proc.sin(sin2));
  var cy3 = (proc.sin(theta) * amplitude / 3) + (point[5] * proc.sin(sin2));

  var cy1i0 = (proc.sin(theta01) * amplitude / 3) + (point[1] * proc.sin(sin2));
  var cy2i0 = (proc.sin(theta01) * amplitude / 3) + (point[3] * proc.sin(sin2));
  var cy3i0 = (proc.sin(theta01) * amplitude / 3) + (point[5] * proc.sin(sin2));

  var cy1i1 = (proc.sin(theta02) * amplitude / 3) + (point[1] * proc.sin(sin2));
  var cy2i1 = (proc.sin(theta02) * amplitude / 3) + (point[3] * proc.sin(sin2));
  var cy3i1 = (proc.sin(theta02) * amplitude / 3) + (point[5] * proc.sin(sin2));

  var cy01 = (proc.cos(theta + (Math.PI)) * amplitude / 4) + (point[1] * proc.sin(sinHalf));
  var cy02 = (proc.cos(theta + (Math.PI)) * amplitude / 4) + (point[3] * proc.sin(sinHalf));
  var cy03 = (proc.cos(theta + (Math.PI)) * amplitude / 4) + (point[5] * proc.sin(sinHalf));

  var cy01i0 = (proc.cos(theta01 + (Math.PI)) * amplitude / 4) + (point[1] * proc.sin(sinHalf));
  var cy02i0 = (proc.cos(theta01 + (Math.PI)) * amplitude / 4) + (point[3] * proc.sin(sinHalf));
  var cy03i0 = (proc.cos(theta01 + (Math.PI)) * amplitude / 4) + (point[5] * proc.sin(sinHalf));

  var cy01i2 = (proc.cos(theta02 - 2 + (Math.PI)) * amplitude / 4) + (point[1] * proc.sin(sinHalf));
  var cy02i2 = (proc.cos(theta02 - 2 + (Math.PI)) * amplitude / 4) + (point[3] * proc.sin(sinHalf));
  var cy03i2 = (proc.cos(theta02 - 2 + (Math.PI)) * amplitude / 4) + (point[5] * proc.sin(sinHalf));


  /* --------comparison bottom points---------- */

  var yScale = 0;
  var yScale2 = 0;
  var yScale3 = 0;

  if (index < (pointsLength) / 2) {
    if (index === (pointsLength / 2) - 1) {
      cy03 = point[5];
    }

    if (index === 0 || index === 1) {
      cy01 = cy01i0;
      cy02 = cy02i0;
      cy03 = cy03i0;

      if (index === 1) {
        cy03 = cy03i0 / (amplitude / 55.5);
        cy02 = cy02i0 / (amplitude / 55.5);
      }
    }

    if (index === 2 || index === 3) {
      cy01 = cy01i2;
      cy02 = cy02i2;
      cy03 = cy03i2;

      if (index === 3) {
        cy03 = cy03i2 / (amplitude / 56.8);
        cy02 = cy02i2 / (amplitude / 55.8);
      }
    }

    if (proc.mouseX > proc.width / 2.5 && proc.mouseX + 80 <= proc.width / 1.2) {

      if (index === 1) {
        cy01 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 2.3, cy01 / 2, 0.5)
        cy02 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 2.3, cy02 / 3, 0.5)
        cy03 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 2.3, cy03 / 3, 0.5) - 70
      }
      if (index === 0) {
        cy01 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 2.3, cy01 / 3, 0.5)
        cy02 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 2.3, cy02 / 3, 0.5)
        cy03 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 2.3, cy03 / 2, 0.5)
      }

    } else if (proc.mouseX > proc.width / 3 && proc.mouseX + 80 <= proc.width / 1.5) {

      if (index === 2) {
        cy01 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 2, cy01, 0.5)
        cy02 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 2, cy02, 0.9)
      }
      if (index === 1) {
        cy01 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 2, cy01, 1)
        cy02 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 2, cy02, 0.5)
        cy03 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 2, cy03, 0.5)
      }

    } else if (proc.mouseX > proc.width / 4 && proc.mouseX + 80 <= proc.width / 2.5) {

      if (index === 2) {
        cy01 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 1.8, cy01, 0.5)
        cy02 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 1.8, cy02, 0.5)
        cy03 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 1.8, cy03, 0.5)
      }
      if (index === 1) {
        cy03 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 1.8, cy03 - 100, 0.5)
      }
      if (index === 3) {
        cy01 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 1.8, cy01, 0.5)
        cy02 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 1.8, cy02, 0.5)
        cy03 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 1.8, cy03, 0.7)
      }

    } else if (proc.mouseX > proc.width / 7 && proc.mouseX + 80 <= proc.width / 3) {

      if (index === 4) {
        cy01 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX, cy01 - 50, 0.4)
        cy02 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX, cy02, 0.9)
        cy03 = cy03 + 10
      }

      if (index === 3) {
        cy01 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX, cy01, 0.9)
        cy02 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX, cy02 - 50, 0.6)
        cy03 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX, cy03 - 50, 0.5)
      }

    } else if (proc.mouseX > proc.width / 16 && proc.mouseX + 80 <= proc.width / 5) {

      if (index === 4) {
        cy01 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX + 80, cy01, 0.5)
        cy02 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX + 80, cy02, 0.5)
        cy03 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX + 80, cy03, 0.5)
      }
      if (index === 3) {
        cy01 = point[1];
        cy03 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX / 1.5, point[5] + 70, 0.5)
      }
      if (index === 5) {
        cy01 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX + 90, cy01, 0.5)
        cy02 = proc.lerp(proc.mouseX + 90, cy02, 0.5)
        cy03 = point[5]
      }

    }

    proc.bezierVertex(
      point[0], cy01 + proc.sin(a) * -4,
      point[2], cy02 + proc.sin(a) * -4,
      point[4], cy03 + proc.sin(a) * -4
    );
  }

  /* --------comparison top points---------- */

  if (index >= (pointsLength) / 2) {

    if (index === pointsLength - 1) {
      cy3 = point[5];
    }

    if (index === pointsLength - 1 || index === pointsLength - 2) {
      cy1 = cy1i0;
      cy2 = cy2i0;
      cy3 = cy3i0;

      if (index === pointsLength - 1) {
        cy3 = point[5];
      } else {
        cy2 = cy2i0 / (amplitude / 55.5);
        cy1 = cy1i0 / (amplitude / 55.5);
      }
    }

    if (index === pointsLength - 3 || index === pointsLength - 4) {
      cy1 = cy1i1;
      cy2 = cy2i1;
      cy3 = cy3i1;

      if (index === pointsLength - 3) {
        cy2 = cy2i1 / (amplitude / 55.5);
        cy3 = cy3i1 / (amplitude / 58.5);
      }
    }

    if (index === pointsLength - 5 || index === pointsLength - 6) {
      cy1 = cy1;
      cy2 = cy2;
      cy3 = cy3;

      if (index === pointsLength - 5) {
        cy2 = cy2 / (amplitude / 55.5);
        cy3 = cy3 / (amplitude / 55.5);
      }
    }

    proc.bezierVertex(
      point[0], cy1 - yScale + proc.sin(a),
      point[2], cy2 - yScale2 + proc.sin(a),
      point[4], cy3 - yScale3 + proc.sin(a)
    );
  }

  theta += 0.004;
  theta01 += 0.0042;
  theta02 += 0.0044;
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.4.8/processing.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your snippet throws an exception.  If you get the snippet to run, we will be better equipped to help you.

Comment: Note that I just archived Pjs, and I can strongly recommend using p5js instead.

Comment: @JonathanWilson , I dont know why snippet not work.. There is a link to this example on codepen with the same rewrited to p5.js code: codepen.io/todoryshyna-maryna/pen/wQbdXO?editors=0010

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ,  Thanks for recommendation, later I will rewrite this code with p5.js.

Comment: @Mar having a quick skim through the code, there's a lot of copy/paste action going on, especially around the mouse interaction part. Within that section, as far as I tell, you're hard coding areas with different conditions: these will break your motion into section as you exit one mouse area and enter another. Try to re-write that part without such thresholding if/else conditions (e.g. map mouse coordinates instead). It feels you're trying to achieve something [like this](http://paperjs.org/examples/future-splash/)